# A simple Flask server with connexion cannot be distribuate with pyinstaller

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller, connexion

## Context

I’m trying to distribute my python server that uses [connexion](https://github.com/spec-first/connexion) with [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/).

Unfortunately, the executable product not pyinstaller does not work. Of the first request an error 500 is issued while it is not in "normal" mode.

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 419, in run_asgi
  File "uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
  File "connexion/middleware/main.py", line 497, in __call__
    self.app, self.middleware_stack = self._build_middleware_stack()
  File "connexion/middleware/main.py", line 338, in _build_middleware_stack
    app.add_api(
  File "connexion/apps/flask.py", line 141, in add_api
    self.app.register_blueprint(api.blueprint)
  File "flask/sansio/scaffold.py", line 46, in wrapper_func
  File "flask/sansio/app.py", line 599, in register_blueprint
  File "flask/sansio/blueprints.py", line 310, in register
ValueError: The name '/swagger' is already registered for a different blueprint. Use 'name=' to provide a unique name.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:56490 - "GET /swagger/ui/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
```

I created a simple server available on GitHub: [repository](https://github.com/Brinfer/helloworld-connexion)

## The question

Does anyone know why I have this error and how I can correct it?

I tried changing the server url and changing when the API is initialized, but it didn't change anything.

The aim would be to be able to distribute a server with a simple executable on any linux system.